# dplyr, create a column conditional on presence or absence or text in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I use dplyr. I would like to create a new column called "disease" with yes or no designation based on another column called description. If the description is NA then the value in the new column should be "N", if there is any text now in the description the value in the new column should be "Y". I tried the following code:

```
data%>%
 mutate(disease= ifelse( is.na(Description)),"N", "Y")
```

Comment: parentheses are wrong

Comment: You tried and? does it work? if not I bet that `NA` are not real `NA`s but stings with the text `NA`. just remove the `is.na` and use `if else(Description == "NA", "N", "Y")`

Answer (score 2):

There is a really simple solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, disease := ifelse( is.na(cyl), "N", "Y")]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` to do this

```
transform(data, disease = c("Y", "N")[is.na(cyl)+1])
```